# How to split multi-values from two different columns and display split value from one column against split value of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, delimiter, multivalue

I have two columns as follows:

| Repay_Aount | Repay_Ref |
| --- | --- |
| 150.063829.07 | T21Q1P-20210529T21XYN-20210428 |
| 160.1216502429.49 | T21YMG-20210628T21GVX-20210531T21Q1P-20210529 |
| 115.9104.2826001461.47 | T21JK9-20210731T21JG1-20210731T21QZP-20210724T21YMG-20210628 |

`Repay_Amount` has some amounts separated by a unicode character ``.

The `Repay_Ref` too has some values separated by `` but, if you notice, every multi-value in each cell ends with a date.

I want to display just the date from `Repay_Ref` against the corresponding `Repay_Amount` amount.

What I want to achieve is:

| Repay_Aount | Repay_Ref |
| --- | --- |
| 150.06 | 20210529 |
| 3829.07 | 20210428 |
| 160.12 | 20210628 |
| 1650 | 20210531 |
| 2429.49 | 20210529 |
| 115.9 | 20210731 |
| 104.28 | 20210731 |
| 2600 | 20210724 |
| 1461.47 | 20210628 |

I tried the following query but couldn't get the desired results. There was duplication.

```
SELECT      REPAY_AMOUNT,
            RA.Value AS [SPLIT_REPAY_AMOUNT],
            RR.Value AS [SPLIT_REPAY_ref],
            REPAY_ref
FROM        InsightImport.dbo.AA_BILL_DETAILS bil
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'') RA
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPAY_ref, N'') RR
```

Any help shall be appreciated!

Comment: What is the SQL Server version?

Comment: The correct answer is `Don't store such data in the first place`. You just found out how difficult it is to query such data.

Comment: @Zhorov: v18.12.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a splitter function, that returns the ordinal position of each substring. Starting from SQL Server 2022 `STRING_SPLIT()` supports an optional `enable_ordinal` parameter.

For earlier versions a JSON-based approach is an option. The idea is to transform the stored text into a valid JSON array (`115.9104.2826001461.47` into `["115.9","104.28","2600","1461.47"]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()` and default schema. The result is a table with columns `key`, `value`, `type` and the `key` column holds the index of the element in the specified array.

**SQL Server 2022:**

```
SELECT RA.[value] AS [SPLIT_REPAY_AMOUNT], RR.[value] AS [SPLIT_REPAY_ref]
FROM AA_BILL_DETAILS
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'', 1) RA
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPAY_ref, N'', 1) RR
WHERE RA.[ordinal] = RR.[ordinal]
```

**SQL Server 2016+:**

```
SELECT RA.[value] AS [SPLIT_REPAY_AMOUNT], RR.[value] AS [SPLIT_REPAY_ref]
FROM AA_BILL_DETAILS
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_AMOUNT, N'', '","'), '"]')) RA
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(REPAY_REF, N'', '","'), '"]')) RR
WHERE RA.[key] = RR.[key]
```

Comment: Thanks mate!
The second one worked like a charm. Though I have latest SSMS installed. That is, v18.12.1

Comment: @NaumanKhan, glad to help. As a note, SSMS is a client tool and its version is different from the SQL Server version.

Comment: Got it, @Zhorov